# Replace some text after a string with Regex and Gsub in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

It's a simple question, but I'm not good with Regex. (I tried many expressions without success)

I want to replace all the text (replace for nothing) after a pattern.

My pattern is something like this:

```
/canais/*/
```

My data is:

```
/canais/b3/conheca-o-pai-dos-indices-da-b3/
/canais/cpbs/cvm-abre-audiencia-publica-de-instruc
/canais/stocche-forbes/dividendo-controverso/
```

The desired result is:

```
/canais/b3/
/canais/cpbs/
/canais/stocche-forbes/
```

How can I do it with gsub?

Thanks

Comment: `dirname(txt)` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following `sub`:

```
x <- c("/canais/b3/conheca-o-pai-dos-indices-da-b3/","/canais/cpbs/cvm-abre-audiencia-publica-de-instruc","/canais/stocche-forbes/dividendo-controverso/")
sub("^(/canais/[^/]+/).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/rp13e9)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(/canais/[^/]+/)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1`) capturing:

  - `/canais/` - a substring `/canais/`
  - `[^/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
  - `/`  - a slash
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of string.

Comment: Many thanks Wiktor. Works fine! And thanks for the explanation, will help in other cases. I had some rows in the data which have `/category/canais/name/`, then I changed a little: `gsub(".*(/canais/[^/]+/).*", "\\1", x)` .

Comment: @DiegoGaona: I would use a [lazy `.*?` at the beginning](http://ideone.com/9tynxM).

Comment: what would be the difference between the `.*` and the `.*?` ? With the first option, worked in my tests too, but could get a error in some case... I don't know.

Comment: `.*?` matches as few chars as possible, up to the *first* occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns. `.*` matches as many as possible, up to the *last* occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns.